# Strategy for complete website access audit and reporting

Tags: architecture, logging, audit-trail

I am looking for some pointers to improve on a solution for the below problem. Even though I am working with a Unix toolchain I am more after a general approach rather than an implementation.

Here we go:

Every access to the website should be logged and business users should be able to report on it in near-realtime (a 5 minute delay is acceptable). Reporting will be done filtered by user or time period or a combination of both.

Anonymous user access is logged as well and information prior to the login should be tied to the registered user once the anonymous user logs in.

I want to log every page access (GET or POST) plus any parameters plus timestamp.

The reporting requirement is: "Tell me what User ID 1 did between 11:15am and 11:18am"

And the response should be:

- At 11:15:23 he came to the homepage.
- At 11:15:49 he went the about us page.
- At 11:16:23 he went to the login page.
- At 11:16:34 he tried to login with username "hacked".
- At 11:16:38 the login request failed - username/password incorrect
- At 11:16:45 he logged in with username "myuser"
- At 11:17:12 he went to the products page.

A solution would be to insert all this using session ID as a primary key and account id and the request data into a db.

In order to not bog down the DB plug a message queue in between and have delayed writes to the database.

However with the amount of data in the database, reporting could quickly become slow.

I am aware of solutions like [woopra](http://www.woopra.com) - however I would like to keep the visitor data internally and also like the idea of in-house reporting with in-house role based access to data, etc.

**Edit**: How have you done something like this in the past or how would you go about it if you had a complete choice of options?

Comment: I don't see a question in there.

Answer (score 0):

An easier approach to do some of those things immediately would be is to implement google analytics without much overhead on your server/application.

The downside of using that would be is that events are not so much as in real time ... it is couple of hours off.

The other solution would be is to implement the messaging solution to a separate database and then re

Comment: Could you please complete that answer? There is a chunk cut off. Google Analytics as you mention is delayed so not an ideal solution. On top of that Google Analytics does not support POST parameters AFAIK.